# How to print a list of different objects in python?

Tags: python, string, list, oop, printing

I have a list (`River`) of randomly selected objects(`Bear` and `Fish`) and I want to print the list with the following format:

```
[B, F, B, ...]
```

(is an example of randomly selected objects). However when I print my `River` instance I get:

```
[<class '__main__.Bear'>, <class '__main__.Fish'>, <class '__main__.Fish'>, <class '__main__.Fish'>, <class '__main__.Bear'>, ....]
```

Why is this happening? any suggestions?

```
class Bear:
    def __init__(self):
        print()

    def __str__(self):
        return str('B')

    def __repr__(self):
        return self

class Fish:
    def __init__(self):
        print()

    def __str__(self):
        return str('F')

    def __repr__(self):
        return self

class River:
    #simulate based on river length
    INITIAL_RIVER_LENGTH=20


    def __init__(self):
        self._river=[None]*self.INITIAL_RIVER_LENGTH

    def __str__(self):
        return str([i for i in self._river])

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self)

    def fillRiver(self):
        self._river=[random.choice([Bear,Fish]) for i in range(0,self.INITIAL_RIVER_LENGTH)]


riv=River()
riv.fillRiver()
print(riv)
```

Comment: In your case, River contains a list of class objects (`Bear`, `Fish`,...), not list of class instances (`Bear()`, `Fish()`,...) and the print shows that.

Comment: Please fix your post to reflect your code accurately. We can't be sure you haven't made a mistake with your indentation, for example.

Comment: In future, when you paste code, select the pasted text and use the `{}` button on the toolbar to indent the whole block. Don't try to 'repair' indentation by only indenting selected lines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are storing **classes** in the river:

```
random.choice([Bear,Fish])
```

So you get a list of classes:

```
[<class '__main__.Bear'>, ...
# ^^^^^
```

You'd have to *call* your randomly chosen class to create instances:

```
random.choice([Bear, Fish])()  # the () calls the class
```

Now you have a new problem:

```
>>> random.choice([Bear, Fish])()

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: __repr__ returned non-string (type Fish)
```

because you are returing `self` from your `__repr__` method. Return a string value; perhaps by using `return str(self)`, but it is better to just implement *only* `__repr__`, because if `__str__` is missing then Python falls back to `__repr__` automatically.

The following code works; note that I removed the `__init__` methods for `Fish` and `Bear`, there is no point in using `print()` to output a newline when you create one of those:

```
class Bear:
    def __repr__(self):
        return 'B'

class Fish:
    def __repr__(self):
        return 'F'

class River:
    #simulate based on river length
    INITIAL_RIVER_LENGTH=20

    def __init__(self):
        self._river = [None] * self.INITIAL_RIVER_LENGTH

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self._river)

    def fillRiver(self):
        self._river = [
            random.choice([Bear,Fish])() 
            for i in range(self.INITIAL_RIVER_LENGTH)
        ]
```

Demo:

```
>>> riv = River()
>>> riv.fillRiver()
>>> riv
[F, B, B, B, B, F, B, F, B, F, F, B, F, F, F, B, B, B, F, F]
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of returning `self` in `__repr__`, return the character denoting each creature:

```
import random
class Bear:
  def __init__(self):
     print()
  def __str__(self):
    return str('B')
  def __repr__(self):
    return 'B'

class Fish:
  def __init__(self):
     print()
  def __str__(self):
     return str('F')
  def __repr__(self):
     return 'F'

class River:
   INITIAL_RIVER_LENGTH=20
   def __init__(self):
      self._river=[None]*self.INITIAL_RIVER_LENGTH
   def __str__(self):
      return str([i for i in self._river])
   def __repr__(self):
     return str([i for i in self._river])
   def fillRiver(self):
     self._river=[random.choice([Bear(),Fish()]) for i in range(0,self.INITIAL_RIVER_LENGTH)]

r = River()
r.fillRiver()
print(r)
```

Output:

```
[B, F, F, F, B, B, F, B, F, B, B, B, F, F, B, B, F, B, F, F]
```